# Malformed reply from socks server in maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, socks

I create the maven project in netbeans 8.0 and add the java class with in that project that prints helloworld.when i try to run the project it display the below error and takes 15minutes to complete the run.

```
 cd C:\Users\selva\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SelvaMaven; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_05" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.selvamaven.SelDur\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_05\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom
Oct 09, 2014 12:11:04 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
Oct 09, 2014 12:11:05 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
Oct 09, 2014 12:16:05 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
Oct 09, 2014 12:16:05 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
Oct 09, 2014 12:21:06 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
Oct 09, 2014 12:21:06 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 20:02.044s
Finished at: Thu Oct 09 12:26:06 IST 2014
Final Memory: 4M/99M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:pom:1.2.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Malformed reply from SOCKS server -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

How to solve this problem?Any Help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: check your Maven settings.xml - if it uses HTTP proxy settings, check if they are valid

Comment: which settings.xml, m2/settings.xml or maven/conf/settings.xml?

Comment: You have a SOCKS proxy configured somewhere that isn't a SOCKS proxy. Possibly it is an HTTP proxy for example.

Comment: i am not configured socks proxy in my project,ide and system.

Comment: If you execute Maven directly from the command line, does it show the same error?

Comment: m2/settings.xml or maven/conf/settings.xml can both contain proxy configuration iirc

Comment: @mjn,yes,Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plug
ns/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plu
ins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ins
all-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed
to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-
lugin:jar:2.4

Comment: If you didn't have a SOCKS proxy configured somewhere you couldn't possibly get this error. You may not know where it is, or have done it yourself, but it's there somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

nstead of using the maven bundled with netbeans install maven on your pc and have netbeans refer to it.
Then edit the /conf/settings file with your proxy configuration:

```
 <proxies>
   <proxy>
   <active>true</active>
   <host>yourproxy</host>
     <port>8080</port>
   </proxy>
 </proxies>
```

Then put [wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-lightweight/2.2/wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar) in your maven /lib/ext directory.

Comment: If you are using maven 3.x that the latest version of wagon-http-lightweight (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.wagon/wagon-http-lightweight/2.10) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

See

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233170

one comment recommends to use the bundled Maven version in NetBeans as a workaround.